# JavaScript replace() method not deleting correct lines

Tags: javascript, methods, replace

I have a sdp and it has multiple lines. I want to replace one line with `" "` or remove it. I tried:

```
obj.sdp = obj.sdp.replace(/a=line5:[\w\W]*\n|\r/gi, "" );
```

for delete line 5 but it is deleting line 5 and also other lines that comes after line 5. I used `\n|\r` for delete until here. Also I when I use

```
sdp = sdp.replace(/a=line5:0.*$/mg, "");
```

Netbeans give me "Insecure '.' error".

Comment: Please show us your full code

Answer (score 1):

The *OR* `|` in your *RegExp* is excluding `a=line5:` and therefore when used with the `g`lobal flag, the `\r` matches every `\r` in your *String*, you probably want

```
/(a=line5:[^\r\n]*)(?:\r|\n)+/gi
"$1"
```

Comment: @user3350488 It's not actually insecure if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you described why you used `[^\r\n]` instead of `[\w\W]`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with;

**str.replace(/(a=line5:[\w\W]*?(:\r|\n))/, "" );**

Thanks!